# Convert date format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date format  2011-01-06T06:30:10Z in Excel.I want to just load the date part into a table from excel.How do I get the date part from it.
i.e. 2011-01-06

Thanks

Comment: If you have loaded the data into database, then all you need to do is use `TRUNC`. A DATE always has a datetime part together. And what you see the date looks likr is not the way  it is stored in database. The format is for we human beings to understand. A date is stored in 7 byte in internal format.

Comment: @lalit kumar B Thank you for this information.I will try to load the data ,but before loading I was thinking what column type I should create since it has Z at the end so was not sure if it's timestamp format

Comment: After you load it, use `TRUNC`. It will truncate the time part and will display only the date part. If this is a part of your requirement, let me know, I will add it as answer

Comment: And do NOT use `PL/SQL` tag for `SQL` questions. Both are different.

Comment: I get the trunc part, but my issue was loading "2011-01-06T06:30:10Z" value into a table with only date part.Or even if I have to load the data as is, I have to create a varchar2 type column. Correct?

Comment: No, **never** use `VARCHAR2` for dates. Always use the `DATE` datatype.

Comment: NEVER stores dates/times in a VARCHAR2 data type column. Sooner or later you will face a problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE('2011-01-06T06:30:10Z', 'T', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') as date) from dual
```

Comment: You don't need the `REPLACE`, simply do `cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2011-01-06T06:30:10Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') as date)`

Comment: @Wernfried Yep! that worked too. Thank you.It would be definitely help in quick processing

Answer (score 0):

I think, some more explanation is needed.

Loading data into database is one part, and displaying it after fetching is another part.

If you have loaded the data into database, then all you need to do is use `TRUNC`. It will truncate the `time` portion and will display only the `date` portion.

A DATE always has a datetime part together. `TIMESTAMP` is an extension to the `DATE` type. And what you see the date looks like is not the way it is stored in database. The format is for we human beings to understand. A date is stored in 7 byte in internal format.

**More information** Based on OP's question via comments

**NEVER** store a **DATE** as **VARCHAR2** datatype. A date is not a string literal. Oracle provides lot of `FORMAT MODELS` to display the datetime the way you want. Sooner or later, you will run into performance issues due to data conversion. Always use explicit conversion to convert a literal to a perfect `DATE` to compare it with other date value.

Comment: Okay, I was talking about converting and loading the data, displaying is simple.I will now do something like this in excel, "=insert into test values (cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE("&A2&", 'T', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') as date));"

Comment: That is fine. Good luck! You can search google for `But I want to store date like` and you will get a very good article by Ed Stevens, read it. It is very good. I hope my answer gave you a better understanding :-)

Comment: @RajA This is article https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/